# How to Select tables names to this query

Tags: sql-server

I want to select phone numbers from all tables in my databese and names of these tables too. I write a query that shows me all phone_numbers but I dont't know how to select table name to each phone number.  This is my query:

```
 DECLARE @SQL AS VarChar(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT phone_number FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + ']' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name in (select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'phone_number'
 )
```

Comment: this would only work if each table had a column named `phone_number`

Comment: Are you going to use this query in a report or a program? because if not, just use [SQL SEARCH](http://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/sql-development/sql-search/download) and search `phone_number` while selecting the option "Search table" only. This tool is free and integrate into SMSS.

Comment: @AXMIM it seems like he is trying to get All Phone Numbers in the entire database regardless of table. SQL Search will only tell you what tables they exist in

Comment: @adamek339 does this query actually work? Have you been able to get a list of all the phone numbers in the database.

Comment: @logixologist ih that is the case, then this is a duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35945620/4625305)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In SQL Server, how do I retrieve data values from table column names identified in a sub-query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945620/in-sql-server-how-do-i-retrieve-data-values-from-table-column-names-identified)

Comment: Then @AXMIM you are correct. Unless I misunderstood it.

Comment: adamek, check answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945620/in-sql-server-how-do-i-retrieve-data-values-from-table-column-names-identified/35946496#35946496).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution without `CURSOR`. You could combine each query with `UNION` like this.

```
    --SELECT DISTINCT phone_number FROM dbo.Course c

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' SELECT DISTINCT phone_number, '''+ s.name + '.' + t.name + ''' AS TableName 
                        FROM '+ s.name + '.' + t.name + Char(13) + ' UNION' + char(13)
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name ='phone_number'

IF(@sql != '')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = LEFT(@sql,len(@sql) - 6)  -- remove last UNION 

    PRINT @sql

    -- execute sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

I also add column `TableName`: Table of `phone_number`

If you want `TableName` if the first column then change it

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + N' SELECT DISTINCT '''+ s.name + '.' + t.name + ''' AS TableName, phone_number 
                    FROM '+ s.name + '.' + t.name + Char(13) + ' UNION' + char(13)
```

Comment: It,s working but I have one problem. I need to change orders of columns. I want to TableName was first.

Comment: Then change order when concatenate @sql string: phone_number after TableName

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the table name as a constant to the `SELECT` clause.  But, I presume you're going to want to *run* this query, which means you have a few more things to change:

1. You're probably going to want [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql), which requires a *Unicode* variable.  So, you need to `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)`.
2. Do you want one result set or multiple result sets?  I'm guessing you want all the results in one result set, which means you're going to want to use `UNION ALL` between the parts of the query.

So, try something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = N'SELECT '''' AS table_name, '''' AS phone_number FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] WHERE 1 = 0'

DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT  table_name
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE   column_name = 'phone_number'

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + N' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + @table_name + N''', phone_number FROM [' + @table_name + N']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @table_name
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

When I used `[dbo].[SomeTable]`, just use some table that you know exists.  You would also need to modify the query if you want fully-qualified table names, but the above should get you started.